# Need a copy of the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf for apache2 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apache2, ssl

Inadvertently overwrote the contents of the default-ssl.conf file right after I installed apache2.

#### D'OH !!

Yes, I see the same request here [[ThomasReggi - 2012](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157293/i-need-a-file-etc-apache2-sites-available-default-ssl)] BUT that was 3 years ago. In case the contents have changed, can someone please oblige me with a more recent version ?  Thanks kindly in advance.